# Dictionary: Property or indexer cannot be assigned to: it is read only

Tags: c#, dictionary, key, setter, keyvaluepair

I am trying to change the value of Keys in my dictionary as follows:

```
//This part loads the data in the iterator
List<Recommendations> iterator = LoadBooks().ToList();
//This part adds the data to a list 
List<Recommendations> list = new List<Recommendations>();

        foreach (var item in iterator.Take(100))
        {
            list.Add(item);
        }
        //This part adds Key and List as key pair value to the Dictionary
        if (!SuggestedDictionary.ContainsKey(bkName))
        {
            SuggestedDictionary.Add(bkName, list);

        }
       //This part loops over the dictionary contents 
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            foreach (var entry in SuggestedDictionary)
            {
                rec.Add(new Recommendations() { bookName = entry.Key, Rate = CalculateScore(bkName, entry.Key) });
                entry.Key = entry.Value[i];
            }

        }
```

But it says "Property or Indexer KeyValuePair>.Key Cannot be assigned to. Is read only. What I exactly want to do is change the value of dictionary Key here and assign it another value.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Some input data and expected output data could be helpful here. (Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Why do you need a dictionary? From your code it looks like you just want a list

Comment: I am trying to Calculate Pearson Correlation and it needs a KeyValuePair to compare the contents. That is why I am using a dictionary. @dtanabe please check the edited code.

Comment: What are the type arguments for `SuggestedDictionary`?

Comment: @ dtanabe it is a Dictionary<string, List<Tentity>> Type dictionary

Comment: How could you assign a `Tentity` to a `string` then? Or is it actually `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`? If you're trying to reassociate an existing key-value mapping to a new key, then the answer posted by @TheGeneral is accurate.

Answer (score 12):

The only way to do this will be to remove and re-add the dictionary item.

Why? It's because a dictionary works on a process called chaining and buckets (it's similar to a hash table with different collision resolution strategy).

[image]

When an item is added to a dictionary, it is added to the bucket that its key hashes to and, if there's already an instance there, it's prepended to a chained list. If you were to change the key, it will need to to go through the process of working out where it belongs. So the easiest and most sane solution is to just remove and re-add the item.

**Solution**

```
var data = SomeFunkyDictionary[key];
SomeFunkyDictionary.Remove(key);
SomeFunkyDictionary.Add(newKey,data);
```

Or make your self an extension method

```
public static class Extensions
{
   public static void ReplaceKey<T, U>(this Dictionary<T, U> source, T key, T newKey)
   {
      if(!source.TryGetValue(key, out var value))
         throw new ArgumentException("Key does not exist", nameof(key));
      source.Remove(key);
      source.Add(newKey, value);
   }
}
```

**Usage**

```
SomeFunkyDictionary.ReplaceKey(oldKye,newKey);
```

***Side Note** : Adding and removing from a dictionary incurs a penalty; if you don't need fast lookups, it may just be more suitable not use a dictionary at all, or use some other strategy.*

Comment: Very nice and illustrative answer +1

Comment: I have tried with the above code but it says the collection has been modified enumeration operation may not execute.

Comment: That's because you modified the dictionary inside the foreach loop. if you want to process it without exception you can try to get all keys out of it and process them. "var keys = SuggestedDictionary.Keys; foreach (var key in  keys) { DoSomething(SuggestedDictionary[key]); }"